# How to remotely power on nodes on maas 2.0

Tags: 16.04, power-management, maas

I wonder if anyone minds instructing me how to remotely power on a node on maas since on maas 2.0 wake-on-lan is no longer available on power type options you were able to choose from at the maas gui's nodes tab. There is detailed guide about WOL on the Internet but nothing useful & straight regarding other currently available options (such as IPMI). Now "manual" is selected as power type for nodes but I'm really interested in doing it remotely. Please be specific in your guidance & it'd be totally appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll need a specialized adapter to use any of the options, that I'm aware of.  What type of servers are they?  A lot of times, Dell's, HP's, etc.. Will have a built in option that might share one of the LAN ports, it just might need to be enabled.  If you're sure you don't have any option but WOL, I don't know what you would do.

Comment: Hi man, please forgive me for being so late to read and respond to your guide (I'm so depressed lately to get with my uni tasks). Anyway this node I wanted to power on by maas is an Intel core i7. And I just come across something "Intel AMT". Fortunately it is available in power type menu maas gui for enlisted nodes. But 1st of all I couldnt find AMT option in BIOS of that node (which seems pretty fashionable compared to BIOSs I used to), and 2nd what exactly must be done on maas itself to use it while commissioning nodes. I read about "amtterm" package but no clear instruction so far found.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have virtual machines and I can not power on any VM, I receive a Failed Commisioned message. [my post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790061/maas-failed-commissioning)