# MAAS Failed commissioning

Tags: maas

Everyone , I'm receiving this error on my maas controller node:

> provisioningserver.drivers.hardware.virsh.VirshError: Unknown state: apagado

all my machines have this status

> " Failed commissioning"

I'm using MAAS Version 2.0.0 (beta7+bzr5112), with Ubuntu 16.04.

I'm testing in a virtual enviroment, with virt-manager. I can pull my hypervisor

```
maas@maas-server:~$ virsh -c qemu+ssh://martin@10.17.17.1/system list
```

--all

```
Id    Nombre                         Estado

9     nmaaas                         ejecutando
-     node0                          apagado
-     node1                          apagado
-     node2                          apagado
-     node3                          apagado
-     node4                          apagado
```

My maas.log is this:

```
Jun 22 01:58:36 maas-server maas.power: [INFO] Changing power state
(on) of node: node1 (4y3h7q) Jun 22 01:58:36 maas-server maas.node:
[INFO] node1: Commissioning started Jun 22 01:58:38 maas-server
maas.power: [ERROR] Error changing power state (on) of node: node1
(4y3h7q) Jun 22 01:58:38 maas-server maas.node: [INFO] node1: Status
transition from COMMISSIONING to FAILED_COMMISSIONING Jun 22 01:58:38
maas-server maas.node: [ERROR] node1: Marking node failed: Node could
not be powered on: Failed talking to node's BMC: Unknown state:
apagado Jun 22 01:59:08 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] Power state
could not be queried: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 01:59:08
maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] node4: Failed to refresh power state:
Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 01:59:57 maas-server maas.node: [INFO]
node1: Status transition from FAILED_COMMISSIONING to COMMISSIONING
Jun 22 01:59:57 maas-server maas.power: [INFO] Changing power state
(on) of node: node1 (4y3h7q) Jun 22 01:59:57 maas-server maas.node:
[INFO] node1: Commissioning started Jun 22 01:59:59 maas-server
maas.power: [ERROR] Error changing power state (on) of node: node1
(4y3h7q) Jun 22 01:59:59 maas-server maas.node: [INFO] node1: Status
transition from COMMISSIONING to FAILED_COMMISSIONING Jun 22 01:59:59
maas-server maas.node: [ERROR] node1: Marking node failed: Node could
not be powered on: Failed talking to node's BMC: Unknown state:
apagado Jun 22 02:02:08 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] Power state
could not be queried: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:02:08
maas-server maas.power: message repeated 2 times: [ [ERROR] Power
state could not be queried: Unknown state: apagado] Jun 22 02:02:08
maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] node1: Failed to refresh power state:
Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:02:08 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR]
node2: Failed to refresh power state: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22
02:02:08 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] node0: Failed to refresh
power state: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:02:08 maas-server
maas.power: [ERROR] Power state could not be queried: Unknown state:
apagado Jun 22 02:02:08 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] node3: Failed
to refresh power state: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:04:23
maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] Power state could not be queried:
Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:04:23 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR]
node4: Failed to refresh power state: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22
02:07:23 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] Power state could not be
queried: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:07:23 maas-server
maas.power: [ERROR] Power state could not be queried: Unknown state:
apagado Jun 22 02:07:23 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] node0: Failed
to refresh power state: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:07:23
maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] Power state could not be queried:
Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:07:23 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR]
Power state could not be queried: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22
02:07:23 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] node1: Failed to refresh
power state: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:07:23 maas-server
maas.power: [ERROR] node3: Failed to refresh power state: Unknown
state: apagado Jun 22 02:07:23 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] node2:
Failed to refresh power state: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:09:23
maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] Power state could not be queried:
Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:09:23 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR]
node4: Failed to refresh power state: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22
02:12:23 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] Power state could not be
queried: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:12:23 maas-server
maas.power: message repeated 3 times: [ [ERROR] Power state could not
be queried: Unknown state: apagado] Jun 22 02:12:23 maas-server
maas.power: [ERROR] node0: Failed to refresh power state: Unknown
state: apagado Jun 22 02:12:23 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] node3:
Failed to refresh power state: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:12:23
maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] node2: Failed to refresh power state:
Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:12:23 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR]
node1: Failed to refresh power state: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22
02:13:38 maas-server maas.import-images: [INFO] Started importing boot
images. Jun 22 02:13:38 maas-server maas.import-images: [INFO]
Downloading image descriptions from
http://10.17.17.200:5240/MAAS/images-stream/streams/v1/index.json Jun
22 02:13:38 maas-server maas.import-images: [INFO] Finished importing
boot images, the region does not have any new images. Jun 22 02:14:38
maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] Power state could not be queried:
Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:14:38 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR]
node4: Failed to refresh power state: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22
02:17:38 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] Power state could not be
queried: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:17:38 maas-server
maas.power: message repeated 3 times: [ [ERROR] Power state could not
be queried: Unknown state: apagado] Jun 22 02:17:38 maas-server
maas.power: [ERROR] node0: Failed to refresh power state: Unknown
state: apagado Jun 22 02:17:38 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] node1:
Failed to refresh power state: Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:17:38
maas-server maas.power: [ERROR] node3: Failed to refresh power state:
Unknown state: apagado Jun 22 02:17:38 maas-server maas.power: [ERROR]
node2: Failed to refresh power state: Unknown state: apagado
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solve it thanks to the comment of Lucio Menzel.

You only have to place the system locals in

> en_US utf-8

with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Reboot and go.

Answer (score 0):

seems that maas is not expecting the state to be in Spanish, can you change you language setting on your maas controller to English?